# Windows 7: how to bring a window to the front no matter what other window has focus?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm implementing a task-bar replacement, dock-like application-switcher style program. It's doing some unique stuff with OpenGL, and with keyboard shortcuts, so the way it's set up, the window doesn't always have focus. I'd like to implement it such that I can bring an arbitrary window to the foreground, much like a taskbar or an ALT-TAB program would.

However, my code simply causes the application icon to flash in the taskbar. The Windows API documentation says that this is what is supposed to happen, but I'm looking for a way to work around this.

I've adapted my code from the following examples, which say that attaching to the foreground thread should allow you to set the foreground window. Here are the sites:

http://www.voidnish.com/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?code=dlgboxtricks

http://invers2008.blogspot.com/2008/10/mfc-how-to-steal-focus-on-2kxp.html

My code looks like this. Note that it's using the win32 wrappers for python (self.hwnd is the handle of the window I want to bring to the front):

```
fgwin = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
fg = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fgwin)[0]
current = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
if current != fg:
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(fg, current, True)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.hwnd)
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(fg, win32api.GetCurrentThreadId(), False)
```

However, unless my window is the foreground window (which it isn't usually), this just causes the program's icon to flash.

Am I doing the thread attaching wrong? Is there another way to work around this? I figure there must be, as there are lots of application switchers out there that seem to be able to do this just fine.

I'm writing this in python, but if there is a solution in another language I will use wrappers or do whatever is necessarry to get this up and running.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**  I'd be open to a way to make it work only on my particular computer, i.e. a way to enable, on my machine, a way for any application to take focus.

Comment: Okay, but there are plenty of applications which are able to do it. It's clearly possible, and I've found tutorials telling me how. My question is, what am I doing which is causing the code from the tutorial not to work?

Comment: why don't you take some code from one of these tutorials and run that

Comment: That's what I've done. The code I posted is almost the exact code from the tutorial, in a python wrapper (see for yourself at the two links I posted). I'm asking if anybody can tell why my code isn't doing what the pages say it will do, or if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx

Comment: I'm literally rewriting the taskbar in a way that makes that guideline completely insufficient. In any case, the solution was posted above, it's one line of code, so it's clearly not something the Windows API is going too far to prevent you from doing.

Comment: @jmite: That's completely consistent with what Raymond wrote.  The user controls focus on his own computer.  You're the user, you change the setting, your computer acts the way you want.  Just don't go deploying code that changes that setting on my computer.

Comment: If only it were as simple as don't do it or let the user decide.  As a user I hate it when something pops up and steals focus. As a developer I get this as a requirement from customers all the time. They have some requirement that the user enter in a number every two hours and they want the screen to pop up no matter what the user is doing.

Comment: @David There are legitimate use  cases for this. For example if you want to pass focus from your application to another when a user double clicks some link. If your opening the "other" application afresh then it will take focus, but if it's already running and you don't want to start a new process, you just bring the old one to the front. However I wouldn't go as far as changing a setting on the user's computer. nspire's answer works perfectly

Comment: @jmite thanks very much for sharing this solution. My use case is I created a screenshot app. If the user clicks the button "Take screenshot in 10 seconds", the countdown starts and then they go focus other windows and do stuff. Then after 10sec elapses, then I need to pop open the editor so the user can edit and quickly upload. I don't get why your solution works though as docs for `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` says `The calling thread must be able to change the foreground window, otherwise the call fails.` which is same reason in `SetForegroundWindow`docs for failing.

Comment: Docs are here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx -- Also how would you revert this to the default? Like what is the default value to restore it? It's not `0` is it? Note: The old solution I was using was the `AttachThreadInput` as you were, however it would fail if the user had right clicked the windows taskbar, as we can't attach to the system thread or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, but you can use:

```
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0,0,0, "Window Title")
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```

Comment: Not that late, only 9 years :P

Comment: Now 11 @jmite :P

Answer (score 14):

I don't like these suggestions of using `win32gui` because you can't easily install that via `pip`. So here's my solution:

First, install `pywinauto` via `pip`. If you're on Python 2.7.9 or a newer version on the 2 branch, or Python 3.4.0 or a newer version from the 3 branch, `pip` is already installed. For everyone else, update Python to get it (or you can manually download and install it by running [this script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), if you must run an older version of Python.)

Just run this from the command line (not from within Python):

```
pip install pywinauto
```

Next, import what you need from `pywinauto`:

```
from pywinauto.findwindows    import find_window
from pywinauto.win32functions import SetForegroundWindow
```

Finally, it's just one actual line:

```
SetForegroundWindow(find_window(title='taskeng.exe'))
```

Comment: python 3.6 on windows throws: `ImportError: cannot import name 'SetForegroundWindow` ,fixed with `from win32gui import SetForegroundWindow`

Comment: @PedroLobito - I explicitly said not to use `win32gui` - my solution says to use `pywinauto`. You should have imported `SetForegroundWindow` `from pywinauto.win32functions`.

Comment: As it is, your answer doesn't work on python 3.6. `pywinauto` is heavily based on `win32gui` and won''t load properly without it, so I don't see the point of not using it.

Answer (score 10):

According to nspire, whose solution I have tried with python 2.7 and W8, and it works like a charm, *even if the window is minimized* *.

```
win32gui.ShowWindow(HWND, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND,win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)  
win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)  
win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND,win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW + win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
```

- Originally it was *if the window is not minimized*, but thanks to **Whome**'s comment `win32gui.ShowWindow(HWND, win32con.SW_RESTORE)`, it now works in all situations.

Comment: You must restore window before calling SetWindowPos functions. Delphi apps can use "Application.Restore;" function to unminimize. Look for ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE) python call. Just call it everytime it does not harm even if window was already shown.

Answer (score 8):

I've had some code that's been running for years, going all the way back to Windows 95. When double clicking the applications system tray icon I always used Win32 API functions such as BringWindowToTop and SetForegroundWindow to bring my application windows to the foreground. This all stopped working as intended on Windows 7, where my input window would end up behind other windows and the window icon would flash on the status bar. The 'work around' that I came up with was this; and it seems to work on all versions of Windows.

```
//-- show the window as you normally would, and bring window to foreground.
//   for example;
::ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW); 
::BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
::SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

//-- on Windows 7, this workaround brings window to top
::SetWindowPos(hWnd,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
::SetWindowPos(hWnd,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
::SetWindowPos(hWnd,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: It brings it to top, but keyboard focus is not in our top window.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function explains, that this is actually the intended behaviour; processes shouldn't be able to "steal" the focus. However, it's possible to adjust your code so that it works anyway.

Have a look at the remark section of [`LockSetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): it explains

> The system automatically enables calls to SetForegroundWindow if the user presses the ALT key[..]

You can exploit this behaviour by making your program simulate pressing the Alt key using the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function before calling `SetForegroundWindow`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're implementing hotkeys, use [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx).  As Raymond Chen puts it (companion blog article to the one already linked by Chris), ["Pressing a registered hotkey gives you the foreground activation love"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090226-00/?p=19013).

Comment: This is cool but it doesn't work prefectly. Like if user right clicks the windows taskbar in Win10. @jmite solution of `SystemParametersInfo` worked.

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds on @nspire and @nergeia above, and wraps in a method to find the window handle (https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/) into one convenience function:

```
def raise_window(my_window):

    import win32con
    import win32gui

    def get_window_handle(partial_window_name):

        # https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/

        def window_enumeration_handler(hwnd, windows):
            windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

        windows = []
        win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enumeration_handler, windows)

        for i in windows:
            if partial_window_name.lower() in i[1].lower():
                return i
                break

        print('window not found!')
        return None

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312627/windows-7-how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front-no-matter-what-other-window-has-fo

    def bring_window_to_foreground(HWND):
        win32gui.ShowWindow(HWND, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW + win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)

    hwnd = get_window_handle(my_window)

    if hwnd is not None:
        bring_window_to_foreground(hwnd[0])


raise_window('Untitled - notepad')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got mine working:

```
import win32gui
from win32con import (SW_SHOW, SW_RESTORE)

def get_windows_placement(window_id):
    return win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(window_id)[1]

def set_active_window(window_id):
    if get_windows_placement(window_id) == 2:
        win32gui.ShowWindow(window_id, SW_RESTORE)
    else:
        win32gui.ShowWindow(window_id, SW_SHOW)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(window_id)
    win32gui.SetActiveWindow(window_id)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. (2019/08) and the keyboard is active

Answer (score 0):

I saw some great answers above, but needed extra functionality where window name would be a more flexible parameter. On failure it returns false:

```
from win32gui import IsWindowVisible, GetWindowText, EnumWindows,\
ShowWindow, SetForegroundWindow, SystemParametersInfo

#Sub-Functions
def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        resultList.append((hwnd, GetWindowText(hwnd)))

#Prime-Functions
def winFocus(partial_window_name):
    SystemParametersInfo(8193, 0, 2 | 1)
    handles=[]
    EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for i in handles:
        if str(partial_window_name).upper() in str(i[1]).upper():
            ShowWindow(i[0], 3)
            SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            return True
    print(partial_window_name + " was not found")
    return False

winFocus("not existing window")
winFocus("ChroME")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with **pywinauto** in **Python**

```
from pywinauto import Application
main_app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*Office", control_type="Window")
main_win = main_app.top_window()
main_win.set_focus()
```