# Display OpenCv window on top of PyQt's main window

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt4

I have made a opencv project which processes input stream from the video and displays the processed output. I have used PyQt buttons to switch from one output to another. My PyQt window covvers almost the entire screen and when i click on my buttons, the opencv window remains behind the PyQt window. Also, I have made the main window of PyQt my parent window. How can I bring the opencv window on top of PyQt window. I searched for cvGetWindowHandle(), but didn't find it's implementation for python.

I have used PyQt4 and opencv2, and the PyQt window has not been designed using a QtDesigner.

Comment: Can you try some of the techniques [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312627/windows-7-how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front-no-matter-what-other-window-has-fo)? I struggled with this too but something like those solutions eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always wrap `OpenCV` window in `Qt` widget...

```
class QtCapture(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(QtGui.QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.fps = 24
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(*args)

        self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.setMargin(0)
        lay.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def setFPS(self, fps):
        self.fps = fps

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        # OpenCV yields frames in BGR format
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2RGB)
        img = QtGui.QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.video_frame.setPixmap(pix)

    def start(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)
        self.timer.start(1000./self.fps)

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def deleteLater(self):
        self.cap.release()
        super(QtGui.QWidget, self).deleteLater()
```

...and do with it whatever you will:

```
class ControlWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.capture = None

        self.start_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start')
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.startCapture)
        self.quit_button = QtGui.QPushButton('End')
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.endCapture)
        self.end_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Stop')

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.start_button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.end_button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.quit_button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Control Panel')
        self.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
        self.show()

    def startCapture(self):
        if not self.capture:
            self.capture = QtCapture(0)
            self.end_button.clicked.connect(self.capture.stop)
            self.capture.setFPS(30)
            self.capture.setParent(self)
            self.capture.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.capture.start()
        self.capture.show()

    def endCapture(self):
        self.capture.deleteLater()
        self.capture = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ControlWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thankyou for the post. I have already wrapped my OpenCV window in Qt widget and It works fine :)