# Bring to front new windows created with Python using terminal

Tags: python, window

When creating new windows with Python in macOS Sierra, they always appear on the back of the open terminal or other apps. This is happening to me both with Pyplot and Pygame. Is there a way for new windows created with a Python script to appear on top so that they can be immediately seen?

Comment: Hi, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/28548677/8150371

Comment: Hi, I've tried using pywinauto, but I believe it only works in Windows, and I'm currently working on macOS.