# Focus on pygame window

Tags: python, pygame, ctypes

I am using

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 6 )
```

to close the console and leave the pygame window open however I have to click on the window to interact with it. Can I make it so it goes back to the pygame window automatically?

Comment: Perhaps you can focus the window manually - There's some python win32 examples of doing that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312627/windows-7-how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front-no-matter-what-other-window-has-fo

Comment: @Kingsley thanks but i can't get this to work

Comment: How are you launching your code? Do you need to run your script as a windowed application instead of as a console? If you use `pythonw` to launch your script there will be no console window.

Comment: @Eric ok but is there another file type to save it as to always open with python w. I use the console for 'non-pygame' codes

Comment: You can change your file extension to `.pyw` and double-clicking the file in explorer should launch the script in windowed mode.

Comment: @Eric pls post that as an answer so u get some rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python script may be run in windowed mode by launching with `pythonw`, this may be automatically handled by changing the file extension to `.pyw`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313091/7675174) for more detailed information.